# Azure VPN P2S Azure AD Authentication Connection Problem: The operation was canceled by the user

Tags: vpn, openvpn, azure-vpn

I've setup an Azure VPN Gateway according to the instructions on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/openvpn-azure-ad-tenant

However, each time I connect, the AAD Credentials token for the user is received successfully.
But next I get a message saying: "*Dialing VPN Connection xxxxxx. Status = The operation was canceled by the user.*"

I've done everything listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/troubleshoot-ad-vpn-client.

Anybody out there that has a clue?

Answer (score 85):

I found the answer to my problem, so here is the solution (in my case)

1. Open Windows Device Manager
2. Navigate to Network adapters
3. Uninstall all of the WAN Miniport (XXXX) devices
4. Right-click on any item and choose to Scan for hardware changes
5. The WAN Miniport adapters should have re-created themselves.

Try connecting to your VPN again.

Comment: Holy wow this worked - I wonder what the root cause is. Thanks for the info!

Comment: I would say this needs more upvotes but that would just mean that more people are having the problem so not good. All the same though, this sorted me out so many thanks!

Comment: This worked for me. Took less than 5 minutes.

Comment: Seems random as hell, but this really did solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: The issue still exists in 2022 and this is the solution. Thank you

Comment: Worked for me. My error message was in German for some reason! Der Vorgang wurde durch den Benutzer abgebrochen.

Comment: After so many solutions, this solution finally worked for me..
Thanks for helping

Comment: I had the same issue the last couple of days too and there were updates yesterday that may well have caused it.

Thank you for this as it fixed it and maybe the other network issues I have been having :)

Comment: Anybody knows the root cause for this ?

Answer (score 7):

Removing the WAN mini ports from the Device Manager worked for me.
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/azure-vpn-issue/77c101b1-91fe-491d-9765-9a46859110c9

Comment: This also worked for me :-)
This are the two steps:
1. remove all "WAN mini ports"
2. scan for new hardware